# Prevent an element from losing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a lot of `input`s in a document.
We want to open a dialog that generates text and puts that in the currently focused input.

The problem is that, when I click a button or anything else to open the dialog that input loses focus. I can't determine which input has to get the generated text.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    // something should goes here to prevent stealing inputs focus
});
```

Is there any solution to prevent stealing focus by that special button?

Comment: save focus when you click the button and load it on the callback of the dialog or on the close button of the dialog

Comment: Seems good idea, i should test it

Comment: Does not work!! input blur will fire before button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not use a form `button` and just use say a `<span>` make it behave like a button?

UPDATE:

You could use something like

```
$('span').hover(function(){
    focused_element = $("*:focus").get(0);
});
$('span').click(function(){
    focused_element.focus();
});
```

Check out [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QnLRx/)

Comment: ohh really? hmmm maybe you might need to do as @ggzone, suggests in the comments.

Comment: doesnt to do with the lost focus ?

Comment: input blur will fire before span click

Comment: @OmidAmraei You worry about the performance of adding a `focus()` handler in my answer, but then use a solution with not only the `*` selector BUT ALSO a `:focus` psuedo selector? I give up.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `:focus` selector will run just one time, but `focus` event will run every time that all the inputs will get focus. anyway i use `input[type=text]:focus` instead. i voted up for the solution.

Comment: this is how you code javascript when you learn jQuery without having any idea about javascript.
wtf is $("*:focus").get(0)? Do you mean document.activeElement :d

Answer (score 0):

Does your field have a unique ID?  If it does, use that ID to set the focus back to the field when the dialog's save/close button is clicked.

Don't worry about having the focus stolen as much as resetting it once you are done.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to handle every focus and save it in `focusEle`:

```
$(function () {

    var focusEle;

    $('*').focus(function () {
        focusEle = this;
    });

    $('button').click(function (e) {
        console.log(focusEle);
        var c = confirm('Love the cat :3?');
        $(focusEle).focus();
    });
});
```

With HTML as:

```
<input type="text">
<button>Press me!</button>
```

Example is working: http://jsfiddle.net/76uv7/

Depending on @ggzone idea

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, as your `*` selector means when you click the button that becomes the `focusEle`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i guessed even so, but check the example its working

Comment: I have checked the fiddle, for me in FF9 focus is not returned to the text input after you click the button.

Comment: Tested in Chrome and FF, a bit confusing...
You sure you focused the text input before clicking the button ?